# Python ProcessPoolExecutor pas-in single and multiple arg

Tags: python, multiprocessing

It is possible to pass in multiple arguments to `ProcessPoolExecutor` to execute a function that takes in multiple parameters with multiple processes:

```
def fn(a, b, c):
   print(f"{a}, {b}, {c}")

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as exe:
   entries_to_print = exe.map(fn, [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5])
```

This will print:

```
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4
3, 4, 5
```

But what if I would like the parameter `a` to be fixed, and only `b` changes, and `c` stays fixed too. So the output is

```
1, 2, 3
1, 3, 3
1, 4, 3
```

I tried `entries_to_print = exe.map(fn, [1], [2, 3, 4], [3])`. This does not work, since it only prints `1, 2, 3`. The only way I was able to make it work was `entries_to_print = exe.map(fn, [1, 1, 1], [2, 3, 4], [3, 3, 3])`.

But what if the parameter `a` is a large data, and I do not want to make 3 copies of it. Is there another way than just copy the fixed parameters multiple times to make a list?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass a partial function to the `ProcessPoolExecutor` that fixes the value of a and takes only one argument b, as shown in the following example:

```
from functools import partial
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def fn(a, b, c):
   print(f"{a}, {b}, {c}")

a = "1" #"large data"  # Fixed value for a

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as exe:
   entries_to_print = exe.map(partial(fn, a, c=3), [2, 3, 4])
```

In this example, we use the `partial` function from the `functools` module to create a new function that has the value of `a` fixed and takes only one argument `b`, and the fixed value of `c`. The resulting function is then passed to the map method of the `ProcessPoolExecutor`, along with the list of values for b.

Note that we also pass the value of c using a keyword argument (c=3) in the partial call, which allows us to fix its value while still leaving the argument position for b unfixed.

This way, you don't need to create copies of the fixed arguments to pass to the map method, and you can still execute your function with multiple arguments in parallel using the `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 0):

on linux global variables are copied to the children by the fork, you don't need to pass it explicitly and pay for serialization.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def fn(b):
    a, c = costant_vars
    print(f"{a}, {b}, {c}")

costant_vars = ('A','C',)
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as exe:
   entries_to_print = exe.map(fn, ["B", "b", "bb"])
```

on windows and macOS (or using "spawn" on linux) you can pass that large variable in the initializer which is only called once, so you don't end up serializing them more than once.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def fn(b):
    a, c = costant_vars
    print(f"{a}, {b}, {c}")

def initiailizer_func(a, c):
    global costant_vars
    costant_vars = (a, c)


if __name__ == "__main__":  # windows compatibility
    costant_vars = ('A','C',)
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5, 
                             initializer=initiailizer_func, 
                             initargs=costant_vars) as exe:
       entries_to_print = exe.map(fn, ["B", "b", "bb"])
```

```
A, B, C
A, b, C
A, bb, C
```